# FreeRADIUS: custom SQL counter only partially working

Tags: mysql, radius, freeradius

I want to add to my FreeRADIUS installation a custom SQL check counter. Basically it's the same as Max-Daily-Session but limited to the current `Called-Station-Id`.

I added this to sql/mysql/counter.conf:

```
sqlcounter dailycounterlocation {
        counter-name = Daily-Session-Location-Time
        check-name = Max-Daily-Session-Location
        reply-name = Session-Timeout
        sqlmod-inst = sql 
        key = User-Name
        reset = daily
        query = "SELECT SUM(acctsessiontime - \ 
             GREATEST((%b - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(acctstarttime)), 0)) \
             FROM radacct WHERE username = '${key}' AND \
             (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(acctstarttime) + acctsessiontime > '%b') \
             AND calledstationid = '%{Called-Station-Id}' "
}
```

then in sites-enabled/default:

```
[...]
authorize {
    dailycounterlocation {
        reject = 1
    }
    if(reject){
        update reply {
            Reply-Message := "You have reached your daily time limit from this location"
        }
        reject
    }
}
```

And last in a custom dictionary file:

```
ATTRIBUTE       Max-Daily-Session-Location     107      integer
```

This works if the user has a previous session in this reset period (today), but if it's the first session of the day the `Session-Timeout` attribute isn't returned, so the limit isn't enfoced.

If I add the factory `Max-Daily-Session` to the user, during the first connection of the day after the group SQL queries I see this in debug:

```
rlm_counter: Current Time: 1425241760 [2015-03-01 21:29:20], Next reset 1425250800 [2015-03-02 00:00:00]
rlm_counter: reset_db: Closing database
rlm_counter: reset_db: Opened new database
rlm_counter: add_defaults: Start
rlm_counter: DEFAULT1 set to 1425250800
rlm_counter: DEFAULT2 set to 1425078000
rlm_counter: add_defaults: End 
rlm_counter: reset_db ended
rlm_counter: Entering module authorize code
rlm_counter: Searching the database for key 'ALG02MAX'
rlm_counter: Could not find the requested key in the database.
rlm_counter: Check item = 200, Count = 0 
rlm_counter: res is greater than zero
rlm_counter: (Check item - counter) is greater than zero
rlm_counter: Authorized user ALG02MAX, check_item=200, counter=0
rlm_counter: Sent Reply-Item for user ALG02MAX, Type=Session-Timeout, value=200
++[daily] = ok
```

So this way the default value of **200** for `Session-Timeout` (which is in `radgroupcheck` table) is returned.
Why this is not happening for my counter? What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this is to add a counter in the module config, and call it from the `authorize` section of the site config file.

In `modules/counter` add:

```
 counter dailylocation {
        filename = ${db_dir}/db.daily
        key = User-Name
        count-attribute = Acct-Session-Time
        reset = daily
        counter-name = Max-Daily-Session-Location-Time
        check-name = Max-Daily-Session-Location
        reply-name = Session-Timeout
        allowed-servicetype = Framed-User
        cache-size = 5000
 }
```

and then in `sites-enabled/default`, in the `authorize` section, right next after `daily` add

```
dailylocation
```

This will enable the counter to be checked!